# IIS and TOMCAT on one Windows server

Tags: windows, iis, tomcat, webserver

Is it possible to run an IIS and a TOMCAT on one Windows server parallel?
If yes, which problems could appear?

Answer (score 1):

We are running a production environment on Windows Server 2008 with an IIS as frontend, which redirects requests to the Tomcat server. This is for authentication purposes.

IIS is running port 80 and Tomcat 8080. Using the ISAPI Redirector, we are not having any issues, since IIS and JVM doesn't really have anything to do with each other, and run on separate ports.

In the redirector config you map which request should be forwarded to the Tomcat. The remainder will be handled by IIS itself. This can be done using wildcards or simple regexp.